# Condensing API requests into single query using CoinAPI

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm currently building a little hobby project using an API called 'CoinAPI', which pulls data about crypto such as price, volume etc.

I want to pull information on some of the most popular cryptos - and display their price.

Using their API, I believe this is using their 'assets' query: https://docs.coinapi.io/#list-all-assets

However, I can only find two options for querying data:

1. Search for one specific asset at a time and bundle it into multiple requests
2. Search for all assets and retrieve a list (11,000+), and loop through the results pulling out info I need

Neither is ideal - I'd much rather be creating a query which pulls information for assets just on the ones I want, rather than just one and do multiple queries or all in one query.

So at the moment, my Axios requests looks like this:

```
  const [bitcoinPrice, setBitcoinPrice] = useState('')
  const [ethereumPrice, setEthereumPrice] = useState('')
  const [stellarPrice, setStellarPrice] = useState('')
  const [xrpPrice, setXrpPrice] = useState('')
  const [cardanoPrice, setCardanoPrice] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/BTC?apikey=apikey")
      .then((response) => {
        setBitcoinPrice(response.data[0].price_usd)
        console.log(response.data)
      })
    axios.get("https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/ETH?apikey=apikey")
      .then((response) => {
        setEthereumPrice(response.data[0].price_usd)
        console.log(response.data)
      })
    axios.get("https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/XLM?apikey=apikey")
      .then((response) => {
        setStellarPrice(response.data[0].price_usd)
        console.log(response.data)
      })
    axios.get("https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/XRP?apikey=apikey")
      .then((response) => {
        setXrpPrice(response.data[0].price_usd)
        console.log(response.data)
      })
    axios.get("https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/ADA?apikey=apikey")
      .then((response) => {
        setCardanoPrice(response.data[0].price_usd)
        console.log(response.data)
      })

  })
```

This is just so wrong in my opinion - but their reported option of using 'filter asset id' I can't get to work.

For example, this is what I've tried:

> https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/filter_asset_id=btc;eth?apikey=apikey

Which isn't working, but I believe is how they say to structure it.

Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong here? It feels like I'm being really stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API endpoint you are trying to hit is incorrect, you need to you the [following API according to the docs](https://docs.coinapi.io/#list-all-assets)

```
/v1/assets?filter_asset_id={filter_asset_id}
```

Your code can then be updated to

```
const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets?filter_asset_id=BTC,ETH,XLM,XRP,ADA", { headers: {"X-CoinAPI-Key", "YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE"}})
      .then((response) => {
        setCoinData(response.data);
      })
  }, []);
```

Comment: You're right - but it's not worked at all. If I follow how you do it, it throws an 'API Key is invalid' error. If I change the question mark before the apikey declaration to an '&' it just pulls all 11,000 possible currencies.

Comment: You need to use the apiKey for your api call. I updated my code, with how you can add your API key in the axios call

Comment: Thanks for the time taken and response you've edited. Unfortunately, it's still producing all 11,000 results. If you have any more thoughts please let me know, but otherwise will go away and think about it.

Comment: Hey I updated my answer, I had wrongly pasted a different url in my answer, it is not `filter_exchange_id` but `filter_asset_id`. I have tested with my personal key and it works as expected

Comment: Yep - you're exactly right, and it's now working as expected. Thank you for your help.